# Using custom metrics in self-hosted sentry

Tags: performance, metrics, sentry, distributed-tracing

I have started using sentry within my org and loving it so far.
I've been trying to use its performance monitoring tool with custom metrics added.
While I can add custom metrics to the transactions I'm generating in sentry_sdk (for Python), I can't get access to them on the dashboard of our self-hosted installation of sentry.
After a lot of digging, I came across this paragraph [here](https://docs.sentry.io/product/performance/metrics/) which states that

> This feature is only available to organization on our latest plans which include Dynamic Sampling. Customers on legacy plans must move to one of these plans in order to access custom metrics.

From what I gather, I believe their plans in general is to run sentry on their servers. Unless you opt-in to their self-hosted code that can be downloaded from github [here](https://github.com/getsentry/self-hosted/releases/tag/23.1.0).
This is absolutely a bummer because I know my org will not consider moving internal data to third-party servers.
Wondering if someone knows of a solution to this problem. If sentry folks know of (paid) options that enables this feature on self-hosted version or if someone has hacked into their open source code?
I'd also love to hear any out-of-the-box suggestion you folks might have.

Comment: See https://github.com/getsentry/self-hosted/issues/1805 and https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/40240#issuecomment-1287083636

Comment: Thanks a bunch for confirming that self-hosted doesn't support custom metrics. I'm right now trying out OTEL + Grafana Tempo. Do you have any thoughts to share on that?